# How to detect when a properties of PreferenceActivity is modified

Tags: android, preferenceactivity

I have created and class to manage my preferences:

```
public class ConfigurationActivity extends PreferenceActivity{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    }
}
```

I can changed the username in the configuration, but, I would like doing more things when the that happens, I don't know how I could detect that a property has been modified when I'm using this method to manage my preferences.

The xml with the property which I want to change looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/dialog_based_preferences">

        <EditTextPreference
                android:key="user_name"
                android:title="@string/title_preferences_userName"
                android:summary="@string/summary_preferences_userName"
                android:dialogTitle="@string/title_preferences_userName" />
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement the [OnPreferenceChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener.html) interface.

Your declaration would change to

```
public class ConfigurationActivity extends PreferenceActivity implements 
   Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener
```

and you need to implement

```
public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue){
    //your code here
    return true;
}
```

of course you don't need to implement the interface necessarily in this class, but as an example I think it'll do.

For completeness sake: Like `Hoan Nguyen` said, you need to call the method to register your class for Preference changes.

```
Preference textPref = this.findPreference(R.id.user_name);
textPref.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
   @Override
   public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference,
        Object newValue) {
    //Do stuff
   }
});
```

for instance in your `onCreate()` method.

Answer (score 1):

You register for change using `registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener` and `onSharedPreferenceChanged` will be called every time  a  preference is changed. Do as `DigCamara` answer if you want to register for selected preferences only.

Comment: To be able to use that method you first need to implement a class that implements the interface. So, to be fair, (s)he would have to first apply my solution and then make the call you're suggesting.

Comment: @DigCamara you can implements OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener just like OnPreferenceChangeListener. Both methods are valid and depending on what one wants, one method is better than the other. If one care only for one or two preferences than your method in my opinion is better, but if one need to listen for many preferences changed than mine is better.

Comment: is right. I modified my answer but it's probably easier for you if you use his/her answer.